# Assign id to jquery datatable colum filtering textbox or dropdown

Tags: datatables

How can I assign id to a jquery datatable column filtering textbox or dropdown.

I am using columnFilter plugin.
html code:

```
<table id="datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td>Address</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Age
            </th>
            <th>
                Address
            </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody></tbody>

</table>
```

scripting code:

```
 <script>
     $('#datatable').dataTable({

        "processing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "/Employee/AjaxHandler",
        "aoColumns": [
       {
           "sName": "Name"
       },
       {
           "sName": "Age"
       },
       {
           "sName": "Address"
                     ]
       }).columnFilter({
        sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
        "aoColumns": [
                       { type: "text" },
                       { type: "text" },
                       { type: "select"}


        ]
    });
    </script>
```

I want to assign an id to the dropdown list created by the columnFilter plugin for Address column as I can do some jquery operation on this dropdown list change.How to assign id to this dropdownlist or
any other column filtering input type created by the columnFilter plugin

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: I got the solution.I have to use sSelector for this purpose